# TrueStudio - Why does the link static library fail?

Tags: linker, stm32, truestudio

I am using TrueStudio for my own stm32 project. I create 2 file foo.h and foo.c includes 2 functions

```
//foo.h
int add(int a, int b);
int sub(int a, int b);
```

and the implementation of timeout

```
//foo.c
#include "foo.h"

int add(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}

int sub(int a, int b)
{
  return a - b;
}
```

After that, I used gcc to compile a static library foo.a. I continue to make the main file to implement the library to test.

```
//main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  int a = 100, b = 50;

  printf("sum is: %d\n", add(a,b));
  printf("sub is: %d\n", sub(a,b));

  return 0;
}
```

Next, I link the static foo lib to main.c to make an executable file using command is

```
gcc main.c foo.a -o main
```

I ran it and get the result is

```
sum is: 150
sub is: 50
```

That's worked fine prove my static lib was built successfully.
I begin to create a project stm32 from stmcubeMX and linker to this foo.a and the error appeared.

```
undefined reference to 'add'
undefined reference to 'sub'
```

My full code and setting path and build bellow

```
//main.c in TrueStudio
#include "main.h"
#include "foo.h"

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  int a = 200, b = 100;
  int _sum, _sub;

  _sum = add(a, b);
  _sub = sub(a, b);

  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

I am very grateful for any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rename your `foo.a` file to `libfoo.a`, then change the C Linker -> Libraries -> Libraries to just `foo` with nothing in front or in the back. This should cause the final output to be `-lfoo`, which in turn causes linker to search for `libfoo.a` in the library search paths.

Comment: just rename **foo.d** to **libfoo.a** or re-compile **libfoo.a** by gcc. I tried and the result is still occur

Comment: I recommend adding verbose (-v) flag and checking the linker output. It'll show more detailed informations e.g. what paths are being checked for libraries.

Comment: Can you tell me specified what I must to do? Where do I need to add verbose (-v)? Sorry, I'm a new to this

Comment: It's a "tick" in C compiler -> Miscellaneous -> Verbose (-v). It causes compiler to output a lot of additional information during compilation which should help you diagnose your problem.

Comment: I mistake it, I fill -v in Other options of C compiler -> Miscellaneous, when I build the result is very long and I don't understand it